# PHP DateInterval create split second (microsecond or milisecond) interval

Tags: php, datetime, precision, intervals, dateinterval

How to create split second DateInterval in PHP?
For example:

> 0.123456 sec

?

interval_spec of [DateInterval::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

does not have `F` nor `f` similarly to [DateInterval::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) that supports split seconds.

[Relative format listing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) of [DateInterval::createFromDateString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) also does not mention any fraction of a sec.

But the [DateInterval class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) listing shows:

> f
>       Number of microseconds, as a fraction of a second.

I was able to get DateInterval with a split second by using the [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) of two DateTimes with a split seconds

example:

```
$formatStr = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
$dateTimeStr = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.0';
$timeZone = new \DateTimeZone('UTC'); 
$timerDateTimeStart = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($formatStr, $dateTimeStr, $timeZone);

$formatStr = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
$dateTimeStr = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.123456';
$timeZone = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
$timerDateTimeEnd = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($formatStr, $dateTimeStr, $timeZone);

$timerDiff = $timerDateTimeStart->diff($timerDateTimeEnd);
$intervalStr = $timerDiff->format('%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S.%f');
echo 'Interval (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sfract): ' . $intervalStr;
```

gives:

```
Interval (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sfract): 00-00-00 00:00:00.123456
```

since DateTime supports the split second [time_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) in its constructor and [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) understands

> u     Microseconds (up to six digits)     Example: 45, 654321

BTW: don't you think that `u` in case of working with the `DateTime` and `F` or `f` in case of `DateInterval` has a potential for making your day a little bit less boring?

One of my workaround could be to create two `DateTime` with a split second precision and then `diff` to get the `DateInterval` with the same split second precision but I would like to get the same result with just the DateInterval.

Do you know how to create `DateInterval` having `0.123456 sec` by using just the `DateInterval`?

Solution based on the accepted answer:

```
$dateInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString("1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 1 second, 123456 microsecond");
$intervalStr = $dateInterval->format('%D %H:%I:%S.%F');
echo 'Interval (dd hh:mm:ss.sfract): ' . $intervalStr . PHP_EOL;
```

gives:

```
Interval (dd hh:mm:ss.sfract): 01 02:03:01.123456
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to do this using [`DateInterval::createFromDateString`](https://www.php.net/dateinterval.createfromdatestring):

```
$di = DateInterval::createFromDateString('123456 microseconds');
var_dump($di);
```

Output:

```
object(DateInterval)#1 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["f"]=>
  float(0.123456)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ROPeZ)

From the manual:

> **time**
>
> A date with relative parts. Specifically, the [relative](https://www.php.net/datetime.formats.relative) formats supported by the parser used for [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) will be used to construct the DateInterval.

Comment: Just for posterity you can also use `usec`.

Comment: @Nick great finding!. Is `microseconds` mentioned anywhere in the manual for `DateInterval`? Where did you find it? Second question how to combine that with other units let say you want an interval of 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes and 123456 microseconds - is it possible?

Comment: Literally just like that. `var_dump(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes and 123456 microseconds'))` TIAS :)

Comment: I've updated @Nick's answer to include the documentation about valid Time Formats.

Comment: @Sherif actually `1.123456 seconds` won't work, you need to use `1 second 123456 usec` https://3v4l.org/W5AAc

Comment: @Jimmix it needs to be `'1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 123456 microsecond'` (no `and`) but that will work too: https://3v4l.org/O23gD

Comment: @Nick Good catch. I could've sworn there was a fractional format somewhere in there. Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sherif you might be right; I've not come across it but that doesn't mean it's not there